# Login from WordPress to External Site

Tags: wordpress, authentication, external

I'm trying to do a generalized script for any WordPress theme which will display a 'Login' or 'Sign-In' link, then show login username, pwds fields, and upon Submit POST to another site with the login info and log them in.

I've done some CSS and code in some themes' header.php file like this:

```
<div class="sign-in-wrapper">
        <div class="sign-in-dropdown">
            <form name="login" id="sign-in-form" 
            <?php if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "www.mysite.com") { ?>
                     action="https://secure.mysite.com/" 
            <?php } ?>
              method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="thisaction" id="thisaction" value="">
                <b>User Name:</b>
                <input type="Text" name="UserName" size="41" class="forminput1" value="">
                <b>Password:</b>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" size="41" class="forminput1">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="login" border="0">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sign-in-link"><a class="sign-in" url="#top">Sign in</a> </div>
```

It works in some themes but not in others.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Asking for plugins will get your question closed as that's not allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks for that.  Removed that part.